# MBProgressHUD fades / lightens when triggered by this button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

What is going on here?

http://screencast.com/t/WACeaQP00iqb

Here's the code for that button (the three method calls spawn 3 (yes 3; i didn't write the server :D) asynchronous data tasks that take some time to finish):

```
- (IBAction)didTouchClockButton:(id)sender {
[self.dr isUserClockedIn];

hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.dimBackground = NO;

// hail mary
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantPast]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    if (![self.dr isNetworkDead])
        if ([self.dr isUserClockedIn]) { // add clock in / clock out function to this button
            hud.labelText = @"Clocking Out..";
            [self.dr clockOut];
        } else {
            hud.labelText = @"Clocking In..";
            [self.dr clockIn];
        }  

});
```

}

I put the hud dismissal inside a KVO callback, which isn't working yet but first things first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dismissing the HUD the line before I call the method that updates the other view elements. Right now they're both happening near instantaneously so it's fine, although if the view was still updating after the HUD went down that would be lame. So the solution is to not mess with the view while your HUD is active. A messy solution, so if anyone has a better one I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do anything related to the UI on a background thread. Dispatch the MBProgressHUD code on the main thread and see if that solves the issue. Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    if (![self.dr isNetworkDead])
        if ([self.dr isUserClockedIn]) { // add clock in / clock out function to this button
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                hud.labelText = @"Clocking Out..";
            });
            [self.dr clockOut];
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                hud.labelText = @"Clocking Out..";
            });
            [self.dr clockIn];
        }  

});
```

Comment: I thought it was the labels too but I commented that out earlier and it still fades away.

Comment: Is there ANY other code anywhere (maybe in the clockIn/clockOut methods) that might add a view on top or something?

Comment: God, I mean, Mike, you're right about a view getting involved. Those clock methods trigger a KVO callback that swaps the label text and a graphic at the top. So I guess one can't run the MBProgressHUD while updating another view element? hm..